# ParseException when sending an email with zip file attachment?

Tags: java

I am getting an Exception when sending an email with a zipped file attachment, any suggestions?

> Caused by: javax.mail.internet.ParseException: Expected '/', got null
>     at javax.mail.internet.ContentType.(ContentType.java:102)     at
>   javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.updateHeaders(MimeBodyPart.java:1322)
>     at
>   javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.updateHeaders(MimeBodyPart.java:1021)
>     at
>   javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart.updateHeaders(MimeMultipart.java:419)
>     at
>   javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.updateHeaders(MimeBodyPart.java:13

```
private MimeBodyPart makeZipAttachment(AttachmentInfo attachmentInfo) throws IOException, MessagingException {
      ByteArrayOutputStream bos = null;
      ZipOutputStream zip = null;
      try
      {
         bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
         zip = new ZipOutputStream(bos);

         zip.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(attachmentInfo.getName()));

         InputStream inputStream = attachmentInfo.getAttachment().getInputStream();
         byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
         int len;
         while ((len = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            zip.write(buffer, 0, len);
         }
         zip.closeEntry();
      }
      finally
      {
         if (bos != null)
            bos.close();
         if (zip != null)
            zip.close();
      }

      DataSource dataSource = new ByteArrayDataSource(bos.toByteArray(), "application/zip");
      MimeBodyPart mimeBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
      mimeBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(dataSource));
      mimeBodyPart.setFileName(attachmentInfo.getName() + ".zip");
      mimeBodyPart.setHeader(CONTENT_TYPE, "application/zip");
      return mimeBodyPart;
   }
```

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40985782/javax-mail-internet-parseexception-in-content-type-string-text-expected

Answer (score 0):

can not say much until i run the program by myself but try with setting content as well like this mimeBodyPart.setContent